# Iterating over a generic hashmap in java

Tags: java, generics, iterator, hashmap

I have this hashmap in my abstract class Drawn, and my intent is to fill it with every instance of every class that extends Drawn. I initialize the map like so:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, ? extends Drawn> drawns = new HashMap();
```

I attempt to add elements to the hash table like so:

```
//this code is in the abstract class Drawn()
public void init(){
    idCount++;
    setID(idCount);
    drawns.put(idCount,this); 

  }
```

And then I attempt to iterate like so:

```
for(<Integer, ? extends Drawn> E : Drawn.drawns.values()) {
  E.draw();
}
```

Both the iterator and the init() code have compile time errors.
However, if I change the type parameters to Drawn instead of  I can get everything to compile, but then when I add instances of a subclass to the hash table, they are not detected by the iterator.

Comment: Note that you are instantiating the raw type of HashMap. That will be you Unchecked conversion warning. You should change your RHS to `new HashMap<>();`, if already on Java 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the "putting" part in `init` - the problem is that you're saying it's a map of *some type of value* where that type extends `Drawn`, but you're not saying what it is. That means you *can't* legitimately put any entries in. You really will need to change it to a `Map<Integer, Drawn>` - and that should be absolutely fine with subclasses, and the iteration code below will still be fine.

The reason you can't do what you want is that the type system is trying to prevent this sort of problem:

```
Map<Integer, String> stringMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, ? extends Object> objectMap = stringMap; // This is fine
objectMap.put(10, new Object()); // This *mustn't* be valid...
String value = stringMap.get(10); // Or this would be dangerous
```

When you fetch a value from the map, you'll only know that it's a `Drawn` reference - if you want to use any subclass-specific methods, you'll need to cast to the right type. That's unavoidable if you want to have a map that can have multiple different kinds of value.

When you're iterating just over *values* then you can just use:

```
for (Drawn drawn : Drawn.drawns.values()) {
    drawn.draw();
}
```

Or if you need the key as well:

```
// Or Map.Entry<Integer, Drawn> after the earlier change
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ? extends Drawn> entry : Drawn.drawns.entrySet()) {
    // Use entry.getKey() and entry.getValue() here
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be in `put` method. The value type in Map is `? extends Drawn`, so that is the error. He can't add anything into it.

Comment: @RohitJain: Yes, I've addressed that part now. But the iteration part is also completely broken as written in the question.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. I was about to post answer, but you already did. :)

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly well: it think my real error was that I was mistaken in thinking that the instances of the subclass were not not being recognized. Thanks!

Comment: So, as a general rule, should you never declare a data structure with type <? extends T>

Comment: @MaxKessler: No, that's not a general rule - it depends on the context. In particular it can be useful to accept that sort of thing as an *input* parameter. For example, if you want to iterate over something and all you care about is that each entry is a `Drawn`, you could accept `Iterable<? extends Drawn>`. But you don't want to use `? extends ...` if you're trying to *add* data to the collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet: What does the method draw() do? Shouldn't we use something like getClass() ?